# Manipulating through color schemes in ColorData

Tags: string-manipulation, color

So I wanted to manipulate through both the color schemes and the RGB color within that scheme but encountered a problem. I started by defining a function:

```
txt[input_] := InputForm[TextString[input]];
```

Such that I could preserve the quotation marks applied to `input`, needed for `ColorData["input"]`. Then a list of a few schemes was built:

```
list = txt /@ {Rainbow, DarkRainbow, Pastel}
```

giving

```
{InputForm["Rainbow"], InputForm["DarkRainbow"], InputForm["Pastel"]}
```

Which then allows for `list[[x]]`, so that manipulating `{x,1,Length[list],1}` cycles through the scheme in ColorData:

```
Manipulate[ColorData[list[[y]]][x], {y, 1, Length[list], 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Which doesn't output correctly. Taking the part of the list seems to work fine, but the `InputForm["Rainbow"]` inserted into `ColorData[InputForm["Rainbow"]]` seems to be kicking up errors. I've tried a lot of different things but can't get it working. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not have `list` as a list of strings; `list = {"Rainbow", "DarkRainbow", "Pastel"}`.  Or even better just let `Manipulate` have `y` be the list of strings; `Manipulate[ColorData[y][x], {y, list}, {x, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: You might want to compare the outputs of `Head[InputForm["DarkRainbow"]]` and `Head["DarkRainbow"]`.  `ColorData` yields a `ColorDataFunction` when an argument has a head `String` and is the name of a known color scheme.

Answer (score 1):

As Edmund commented:

```
list = {"Rainbow", "DarkRainbow", "Pastel"};

Manipulate[ColorData[y, x], {y, list}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) is a formatting wrapper, i.e. for display to *you*, not for passing between functions. (In most cases.)  You may have wanted [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) or [`SymbolName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymbolName.html) but it is better to simply keep a list of Strings.